# Docker compose up 'Exec format error' loading a library

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm developing a multi-module docker nodejs app with docker-compose. There's an issue with the [natural](https://www.npmjs.com/package/natural) node package needed by a module. It seems that it can't exec it. I tried to rebuild it on the fly with a RUN command, but nothing changed.
Here's the log when trying to run docker-compose up:

```
web_1         | /app/web-server/node_modules/natural/lib/natural/classifiers/classifier.js:32
web_1         |     if (e.code !== 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') throw e;
web_1         |                                        ^
web_1         |
web_1         | Error: Error loading shared library /app/web-server/node_modules/webworker-threads/build/Release/WebWorkerThreads.node: Exec format error
web_1         |     at Error (native)
web_1         |     at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
web_1         |     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
web_1         |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
web_1         |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
web_1         |     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
web_1         |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
web_1         |     at bindings (/app/web-server/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:81:44)
web_1         |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/web-server/node_modules/webworker-threads/index.js:1:105)
web_1         |     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
web_1         |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
web_1         |     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
web_1         |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
web_1         |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
web_1         |     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
web_1         |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "realaffinities",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server/Server.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "big-integer": "^1.6.23",
    "body-parser": "1.9.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-validator": "^3.2.1",
    "knex": "^0.13.0",
    "mysql": "^2.14.1",
    "natural": "^0.5.4",
    "twit": "^2.2.9",
    "url-exists": "^1.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-express-server": "^0.5.3",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha web-server/test",
    "start": "node server/Server.js"
  }
}
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.11-alpine

EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV development
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# add package.json and run npm install before adding the rest of the files
# this way, you only run npm install when package.json changes
ADD /web-server/package.json /app/package.json

RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc g++ python

RUN npm install -g mocha
RUN npm install
```

I don't know whether it's an issue of this particular node package or a knowledge lack of mine. If I run the same application locally on my mac without docker, it doesn't encounter this problem.

Comment: Are node version in your mac and in your dockerfile  same?

Comment: They were not the same, I updated my dockerfile to the same version I have on my mac (8.1.4) and run: docker-compose up --force-recreate --build but the problem is still there.

Comment: It is not a problem related to docker. But the reason it fails to run inside docker is that there are some packages missing in the container.

Comment: I can't see what package is missing.. how can I do?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/codekitchen/dinghy/issues/117) is a very similar case as yours.

Comment: It worked! I had just to remove my node_modules folder. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Someone reported same problem in [this](https://github.com/codekitchen/dinghy/issues/117) issue and his case was similar to yours. As discussed in comments, this worked for you, so I am posting this as answer also:

> It sounds like it's trying to load a native extension that wasn't
> compiled for linux (in the container) -- maybe you previously
> installed the extension on OS X and it's trying to load that binary.
> If you mean this is a node app, try just removing node_modules and run
> npm install again

Fix that worked for you: `rm -rf node_modules`

Answer (score 11):

Create a `.dockerignore` file and add `/node_modules`

Comment: this one was the issue in my case. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers above worked for me. Switching from [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) to [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bcryptjs) was what worked.

Answer (score -1):

docker build --platform linux/amd64 .

Instead of the default arm64, this sometimes works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).